# How to play video from MediaLive through UDP?

Tags: udp, http-live-streaming, aws-media-live, aws-mediapackage

**On AWS, how do you play video from MediaLive through the UDP output group?**

For my use case, I'm building a live stream pipeline that takes an MPEG-2 transport stream from MediaLive, processes it through a UDP server (configured as an *output group*), and consumed by a web client that plays on HTML5 video.

The problem is: the data is flowing, but the video isn't rendering.

Previously, my output group was set to AWS MediaPackage, but because I need the ability to read and update frames over live stream, I'm trying to feed through UDP.

Is setting the output group to UDP the right approach?

The documentation is a bit sparse here. I'm wondering if there are resources or examples where others were able to play video this way as oppose to HLS/DASH.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post.  Yes the UDP or RTP output would be the right choice of output from MediaLive. Appropriate routing rules will need to be used on any intermediary routers or firewalls to ensure that the UDP traffic can reach the client.

You wrote that 'the data is flowing, but the video isn't rendering.' This suggests an issue with the web client.

I suggest adding another identical UDP output to your UDP server and sending its output to a computer (or AWS Workspace) running a copy of VLC player. Decoding that new stream will give you a confidence monitor on the output of the entire workflow up to that point. This will help isolate the problem.

You could achieve the same result with a packet capture or TS stream analyzer if you want to go that route instead. If you go this route, I recommend trying to play back one of the packet captures locally with the web client.